# Chebyshev's inequality, binomial distribution

Tags: probability, binomial-distribution

I'm trying to solve the following problem.

Let $W \sim \mathrm{Binomial}(100,0.5)$. Use Chebyshev's (second) inequality to get the upper bound on $P(|W-50| \geq 100)$.

My solution:
$$\mathrm{Var}(W) = 100\cdot0.5(0.5) = 25 \Rightarrow \sigma = \sqrt{25} = 5$$
and $$k\sigma = 100 \Rightarrow k = 20.$$

According to Chebyshev's inequality

$$P(|X - \mu| \geq k\sigma) \leq \frac{1}{k^2}$$

so in this case, the upper bound is given by $$\frac{1}{20^2} = \frac{1}{400}.$$

The solution according to my textbook, however, is $1/4$. Does someone know how they received that answer?

Comment: Actually the probability is even zero. Maybe it was $\geq10$ in stead of $\geq100$.

Comment: It could of course be that there is an error in my book. It happens quite a lot with this darned book.

Comment: Uh, uh... Write a math-book yourself. Then reconsider your remark (which is quite understandable, though) :).

Comment: I suppose it can't be easy, haha. :)

Comment: @drhap: it might be worth turning your first comment into an answer, since that would produce $1/4$ - there is unlikely to be a better response